# How to connect to a hotspot with dynamic IP address on boot and get a static IP address in RP4 with Kali Linux

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I want to connect to hotspot on my phone automatically when I boot my Raspberry Pi 4 (with Kali Linux installed).

I know that I can edit `/etc/network/interfaces` but the configuration file I have is something like this:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.198
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    wpa-ssid "WIFINAME"
    wpa-psk "WIFIPASSWD"
```

which is great if the hotspot had a static IP address but my phone changes the third part of the IP address `192.168.THIS_PART.1` every time I open the hotspot.

How can set the last part of the IP address to be always the same in the configuration file but also have the third part changed so I can connect with ssh to my RP4.

I'm not limited to using the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone should have a static SSID (name of the hotspot/WiFi network), e.g., `phoneHotspot`, i.e., the `wpa-ssid` in your `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration.

I am not an expert in Kali Linux, but `wpa_supplicant` configuration should do the work, see [this example](https://www.yeahhub.com/connect-wifi-network-terminal-kali-linux/). The theory is that by using this approach the the dynamic IP of your phone shouldn't be an issue. Besides, you can always delete whatever information `wpa_supplicant` cached, and start fresh just with the SSID and the password from your `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

See also [a similar example for Debian](https://linuxhint.com/3-ways-to-connect-to-wifi-from-the-command-line-on-debian/), also using `wpa_supplicant`.

[Arch linux's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wpa_supplicant) also has the `wpa_supplicant` very well covered, as always :)

Let me know if that helped, good luck.